# Contador de Vocales

Tags: python

Me estoy volviendo loco tratando de hacer el contador de vocales, la consigna tal cual dice:

> Ingresar 10 frases. Contar y mostrar la cantidad de vocales solamente de las frases que contienen un punto.

Nos dieron una especie de instrucciones para hacerla pero no entiendo como hacer el programa.

El código es el siguiente:

```
c = str("Frase con vocales")

def contar_vocales(cad):
    voc = 0
    for c in cad:
        if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
            voc = voc + 1
    return voc
```

Al ejecutarlo no muestra nada, se que es porque no tiene ningún `print`, pero al poner uno "se corrompe" el código, pero así solo sin el `print` ejecuta correctamente, solo que no se visualiza nada.

Suponiendo que funciona correctamente el código solo necesito ayuda en poner algún `print`, pero no estoy para nada seguro.

Muchas gracias a los que ayudaron, yo lo habia hecho anteriormente así:

```
for i in range(10):
    a = input("Ingrese una frase: ")
    if a.count(".") > 0:
        def contar_vocales(cad):
            voc = 0
            for a in cad:
                if a in "aeiouAEIOU":
                    voc = voc + 1
            return voc
        print("Su frase tiene: ", contar_vocales(a), " vocales")
    elif a.count(".") == 0:
        print("Su frase no tiene puntos")
```

Comment: Que has intentado para resolver el problema? Puedes leer las reglas para darte una idea de que espera la comunidad antes de responder una pregunta: es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Te sugiero tomes en cuenta lo que comenta, cavpollo, modifica tu pregunta agregando información y lo que has realizado, Revisar [ask] , saludos.

Comment: Mis disculpas... Ahora estoy leyendo y agregue el código que hice hasta ahora

Comment: @ScarK no te preocupes al contrario gracias por mejorar tu pregunta de esta forma seguramente obtendrás la ayuda requerida!, saludos.

Comment: Podrias aclarar cual es el problema con tu solucion? =)

Comment: Me explaye un poco más, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: "solamente de las frases que contienen punto",¿en donde? al final al inicio o ¿dentro de la palabra?

Comment: Supongo que al final, solamente dice eso la consigna

Comment: ¿Scark que quieres decir con "se corrompe"? ¿Que código en concreto intentas ejecutar  cuando esto ocurre?¿Qué excepción obtienes? para obtener el resultado solo necesitas hacer `print(contar_vocales(c))` el casting a `str` en `c` sobra, `c = "Frase con vocales"`.

Comment: He formateado el código de la pregunta, mira que la identación en tu caso sea la mostrada. Para formatear código solo tienes que copiarlo y pegarlo, luego seleccionas todo el código pegado y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor, de esta forma queda formateado como código y no pierdes la identación.

Comment: Justo lo solucione, muchas gracias por su ayuda, en base de algo que me dijeron se me prendió la lamparita jeje

Comment: Ahora solo tengo que ver como agregar las otras 9 frases y que quede bien

Comment: @ScarK me parece que tienes que ingresar 10 frases en base a eso mostrar si tienen o no vocales si estas tienen un "." puedes hacer un for y obtener las frases usando input()

Comment: Exacto, mostrar la cantidad de vocales de las frases que contengan un ".", estoy viendo como organizar todo, igualmente si no puedo mañana tengo clases con el profesor, estoy tratando de terminarlo antes nomas

Answer (score 1):

En realidad el codigo funciona! Si llamas a la funcion con una frase adentro de los paraentesis cambiando el return por el print te devuelve un resultado correcto. Lo que te falto es llamar a la funcion con una frase como argumento y funciona. Por ahi lo que te confunde es que definis c al principio pero cuando definis la funcion lo reescribis, el c de la funcion no tiene nada que ver con el de arriba lo que evalua la funcion es lo que pasas como argumento. Copio codigo abajo:

```
c = str("Frase con vocales")

def contar_vocales(cad):
    voc = 0
    for c in cad:
        if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
            voc = voc + 1
    print (voc)
contar_vocales("hola como andas")
```

Answer (score -1):

Esta es una opción, realizas un for para obtener las frases y almacenarlas en un array, posteriormente buscas si esta frase contiene "." si es así cuentas las vocales:

```
#Declara array
frases = []

#Realiza un for para obtener 10 frases
for i in range(10):
    #Pide ingresar frase
    frase = str(input("ingresa la frase: "))
    #almacena frases en array
    frases.append(frase)

#itera frases    
for frase in frases:     
    #busca "."
    if "."  in frase: 
        #Si contiene "." cuenta vocales.
        voc = 0        
        for c in frase:
             if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
                voc = voc + 1       
        print(frase + " contiene " + str(voc) + " vocales")
```

Comment: Me gusta mas como quedo el tuyo a diferencia del mio jaja

Comment: **CP 301 () Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: @ScarK es lo que requiere tu pregunta, saludos.